# Does an uncountable directed set have an infinite bounded subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, order-theory

Since every uncountable directed set that I check, has an infinite bounded subset (For example $(\mathbb{R},\leq )$ has many such subsets), I want to prove that this question has a positive answer. Does anyone have any idea?
(Thank you)

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio But it should be uncountable . your example is not uncountable

Comment: @JoJomax: The set $X$ could be uncountable.

Comment: Yes. thank you. I found out.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I think you should post that as an answer